# Handler not stopping - Android

Tags: android, android-handler

I created one handler to repeat a task repeatedly and I also want to destroy it within that handler once a condition has been met.

`pinHandler = new Handler();`

Now I created two functions separately to start and stop the task.

```
void startRepeatingPins() {
        mPinSetter.run();
    }
    Runnable mPinSetter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                System.out.println("PinIndwx count is :"+pinIndexCount);
                if(pinIndexCount==(plist.size()-1))
                {
                    stopUpdatingPins();
                    pinIndexCount=0;
                    //pinHandler.removeCallbacks(mPinSetter);
                    System.out.println("Handler stopped by itself.");
                }
                else
                {
                    updatePoint(plist.get(pinIndexCount));
                    pinIndexCount++;
                }

            }
            finally {
                pinHandler.postDelayed(mPinSetter, pinInterval);
            }
        }
    };

    private void stopUpdatingPins()
    {
        pinIndexCount=0;
        pinHandler.removeCallbacks(mPinSetter);
        System.out.println("Called the stop function.");
    }
```

Now, the issue is that, if I call the `stopUpdatingPins` function , the handler stops but when I try to stop it automatically from within the handler, it just doesn't stop. Although the `stopUpdatingPins` function does get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change You `startRepeatingPins()` like this, You should not directly call the run. If your run like this then there is no point of removing this from Handler. So attach Runnable with Handler.

```
void startRepeatingPins() {
   pinHandler.post(mPinSetter);
}
```

You added post delay in `finally` that means you are stopping at first if loop and starting again in finally, So it's never stopping. So Change your runnable like this,

```
Runnable mPinSetter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                System.out.println("PinIndwx count is :"+pinIndexCount);
                if(pinIndexCount==(plist.size()-1))
                {
                    stopUpdatingPins();
                    pinIndexCount=0;
                    //pinHandler.removeCallbacks(mPinSetter);
                    System.out.println("Handler stopped by itself.");
                }
                else
                {
                    updatePoint(plist.get(pinIndexCount));
                    pinIndexCount++;
                    pinHandler.postDelayed(mPinSetter, pinInterval);
                }


        }
    };
```

Comment: Why did it stop when I explicitly called removecallbacks but not when I called it within the handler ?

Comment: I explained in my answer itself **You added post delay in finally that means you are stopping at first if loop and starting again in finally** this means you are stopping but you are starting immediately again.